# how to write a thread in ROS

Tags: ros, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know how to write a async thread in ROS. An example would be greatly appreciated.
Edwin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217960/how-to-write-a-thread-in-ros/) by [elthef](https://answers.ros.org/users/9256/elthef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are looking for C++ solution, here is what the Wiki page on [Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) says:

> roscpp does not try to specify a
> threading model for your application.
> This means that while roscpp may use
> threads behind the scenes to do
> network management, scheduling etc.,
> it will never expose its threads to
> your application. roscpp does,
> however, allow your callbacks to be
> called from any number of threads if
> that's what you want.

Please also see [this question with answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/10328/multiple-threads-in-single-ros-node/).

In short: you can choose any threading library you like; ROS nodes and callbacks are thread-safe. However, to avoid extra dependencies it is a good idea to use Boost threads (ROS utilises Boost for many internal components).

Here are [the docs and examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html) for Boost threads. Also, if c++11 compiler is available then you can try std::thread. Or you even can use [POSIX Threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads#Example).

EDIT:

The following example uses Boost threads with ROS. It publishes empty messages to two topics with different rates, which you can easily check with `rostopic hz <topic_name>`.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

void do_stuff(int* publish_rate)
{
  ros::NodeHandlePtr node = boost::make_shared<ros::NodeHandle>();
  ros::Publisher pub_b = node->advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("topic_b", 10);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(*publish_rate);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::Empty msg;
    pub_b.publish(msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int rate_b = 1; // 1 Hz

  ros::init(argc, argv, "mt_node");

  // spawn another thread
  boost::thread thread_b(do_stuff, &rate_b);

  ros::NodeHandlePtr node = boost::make_shared<ros::NodeHandle>();
  ros::Publisher pub_a = node->advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("topic_a", 10);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10); // 10 Hz
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::Empty msg;
    pub_a.publish(msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();

    // process any incoming messages in this thread
    ros::spinOnce();
  }

  // wait the second thread to finish
  thread_b.join();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elthef](https://answers.ros.org/users/9256/elthef/) on 2015-09-25**:
Thank you i will try it out

**Comment by [mrtwister](https://answers.ros.org/users/25260/mrtwister/) on 2016-03-25**:
Was it working with this?